# Monitor which process create a file

Tags: linux, security, virus, monitoring

there are two Linux Servers one is Ubuntu14 and the other is Centos7.
when users connect with *ssh* and work, we found some files like below:
[image]

I couldn't find any tools to find which process creates it.
are my servers infected?

Comment: How about use this command : ls -l `file_name`.

Comment: @oooo, did you read my question? the picture is the output of `ls -l` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't retrospectively determine what process created a file... You have to monitor the system while the file is created.

Use `auditd` to help you out.
Once it's installed and running, run the following as root from the directory listed above:

```
auditctl -w "$(pwd)/1"
auditctl -w "$(pwd)/=1"
```

Once you've seen that the file(s) have been created or modified, run the following:

```
ausearch -f "$(pwd)"
```

You should see output with records that are delimited by breaks (`----`).

I see the following having setup a watch on `/home/attie/testing`, and then using `touch` to create/update it:

```
time->Mon Sep 10 14:41:07 2018
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1536586867.166:1192): proctitle=746F7563680074657374696E67
type=PATH msg=audit(1536586867.166:1192): item=1 name="testing" inode=8442 dev=00:b8 mode=0100644 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE
type=PATH msg=audit(1536586867.166:1192): item=0 name="/home/attie" inode=4 dev=00:b8 mode=040701 ouid=1000 ogid=1000 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
type=CWD msg=audit(1536586867.166:1192):  cwd="/home/attie"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1536586867.166:1192): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffc35557634 a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=69d items=2 ppid=25572 pid=31301 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts2 ses=24669 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" key=(null)
```

Note the following key pieces of information:

- `type=PATH    [...] item=1 name="testing"`
- `type=CWD     [...] cwd="/home/attie"`
- `type=SYSCALL [...] exe="/bin/touch"`

---

Once you've established what's going on, you'll want to remove the rule(s) - this will delete all rules:

```
auditctl -D
```

Comment: thanks @attie, but I don't know in which folder their maybe created.is there any way to control all directory? and so, is it pressure System performance?

Comment: Oh... do they appear randomly? What directory was listed above?

Comment: yes. the above is /root. as I got it appears sometimes in which folder we _cd_ in it and working like _ls_ _vim_ , ...

Comment: I would setup a watch on a directory you've seen the files before - e.g: on something like your home directory... then wait for the file(s) to be created, and check the log.

Comment: Are the files always named `1` and `=1`?

Comment: more times are _1_ and _2_ files and newly added _=1_  file. are there infected?

Comment: These files aren't infected (they are zero bytes), but it would be good to understand where they are coming from - I'd suggest setting up a watch on a folder, and when you see the file in that folder, review the log....